# Type mismatch cannot convert from String to String[]

Tags: java

When I run:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class War {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] deckcards=deck();
        String[] player1cards=player1Cards(deckcards);
    }
    public static String[] deck(){
        String[] Cards = {"spades1","spades2","spades3", "spades4", "spades5", "spades6", "spades7", "spades8", "spades9", "spades10", "spadesJ", "spadesQ", "spadesK", "spadesA", "clubs1", "clubs2", "clubs3", "clubs4", "clubs5", "clubs6", "clubs7", "clubs8", "clubs9", "clubs10", "clubsJ", "clubsQ", "clubsK", "clubsA", };
        return Cards;
    }
    public static String [] player1Cards(String[] deckcards){
        String[] player1cards = deckcards[0];
        return player1cards;
    }
```

I get two errors.

One error tells me

```
Type mismatch cannot convert from String to String[]
```

The other error tells me there is a line breakpoint error on:

```
String[] player1cards = deckcards[0];
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An element of a `String[]` is a `String`, not a `String[]`, but saying that doesn't fix your problem.

Issues of design and style aside, I think your intention is:

```
public class War {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] deckcards=deck();
        // shuffle deck
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(deckcards));
        Collections.shuffle(list);
        deckcards = list.toArray(new String[]{});
        // deal from deck
        String[] player1cards=player1Cards(deckcards, 0, 5);
    }
    public static String[] deck(){
        String[] Cards = {"spades1","spades2","spades3", "spades4", "spades5", "spades6", "spades7", "spades8", "spades9", "spades10", "spadesJ", "spadesQ", "spadesK", "spadesA", "clubs1", "clubs2", "clubs3", "clubs4", "clubs5", "clubs6", "clubs7", "clubs8", "clubs9", "clubs10", "clubsJ", "clubsQ", "clubsK", "clubsA", };
        return Cards;
    }
    public static String [] player1Cards(String[] deckcards, int from, int quantity){
        String[] player1cards = Arrays.copyOfRange(deckcards, from, from + quantity);
        return player1cards;
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: untested code (thumbed on iPhone) and nothing done to fix design problems, but you will have something that works.

Comment: Thank you. This is a huge help. +1.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is here:

```
String[] player1cards = deckcards[0];
```

`deckcards[0]` is an element of an array of type `String`. So it is a String variable. But you are trying to assign it to `String[] player1cards` which is an array of strings which is not allowed in Java.

Comment: Thank you for the response. If you have a solution to this, it would be great.

Comment: Since you are trying to assign a value of type String (deckcards[0]) to a variable, that variable has to be of type String. It will look something like this: `String player1cards = deckcards[0]`. You should look up simple java tutorials like [this one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html), they explain this.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the function: public static String [] player1Cards(String[] deckcards){} ?

Answer (score 3):

This is your error:

```
String[] player1cards = deckcards[0];
```

If you want to copy the first value of `deckscards` into the first value of `player1cards`, then one alternative is:

```
String[] player1cards = deckcards;
player1cards[0] = deckcards[0];
```

According to your code, you are saying that the whole `String[]` is equal to the first value of the other array. That cannot be. If you want to equal two arrays, then:

```
String [] automobile = {"toyota","zion"};
String[] car = {"nissan"};
automobile = car;
```

Hope this helps.